# ansible from MAC to a remote DataDomain which has special filesystem

Tags: macos, ansible

Folks I have an ansible.cfg
[defaults]

```
remote_user = sysadmin
inventory = hosts.yaml
host_key_checking = False
local_tmp = /Users/juergen/Documents/DPSCodeAcademy/ansible/#dev/ddve-aws/ddve6-7.4
```

Further down a playbook

```
---
-
  hosts: ddve
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name:  net show all
      command: net show all
...
```

and the ddve host is a very special linux box which it's own commandset, so regular linux operation do not work. What I was trying is to redirect the tmp dir to a local dir on my mac and just fire a valid command on that ddve host but this fails with:

```
fatal: [3.126.251.125]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo For example, \"help timezone\" shows all commands relating to timezones./.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo For example, \"help timezone\" shows all commands relating to timezones./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1611501684.866448-10774-109898410031575 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1611501684.866448-10774-109898410031575=\"` echo For example, \"help timezone\" shows all commands relating to timezones./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1611501684.866448-10774-109898410031575 `\" ), exited with result 40, stdout output: That doesn't look like a valid command, displaying help...\n\nHelp is available on the following topics:\n\n   adminaccess            ddboost                ntp\n   alerts                 disk                   qos\n   alias                  elicense               quota\n   authentication         enclosure              replication\n   autosupport            filesys                smt\n   cifs                   ifgroup                snapshot\n   client-group           log                    snmp\n   cloud                  migration              storage\n   compression            mtree                  support\n   config                 net                    system\n   data-movement          nfs                    user\n\nType \"help <topic>\" to view help for the given topic.\n\nType \"help <keyword>\" to search the commands for a specific keyword.\nFor example, \"help timezone\" shows all commands relating to timezones.\n\n", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
3.126.251.125              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

but a ssh login is working.

```
❯ ssh sysadmin@3.126.251.125
EMC Data Domain Virtual Edition
Last login: Sun Jan 24 07:21:24 PST 2021 from 95.91.249.86 on ssh


Welcome to Data Domain OS 7.4.0.5-671629
----------------------------------------
sysadmin@ip-172-31-16-174# net show all
Active Network Configuration:
ethV0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:C9:AF:87:AC:7C  
          inet addr:172.31.16.1
```

can you help me what the error is telling

Answer (score 1):

Ansible relies on being able to run `python` on the remote host. If "regular linux operations" won't work, this is probably the problem.

The simplest workaround is to use the `raw` module, which simply executes commands via ssh. This is the *only* module you would be able to use to target the remote host.

```
- name: net show all
  raw: net show all
```

---

It looks like the remote system is some sort of networking device. There are a number of Ansible modules designed to work with switches and other network devices that don't support regular Linux commands, or Python, etc. See the documentation for [Ansible Network Automation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/index.html) for more information. Possibly there is a module for the device you are managing?